# ReactJS - onDrop is not being triggered

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to convert a js project into ReactJS. The goal is to have the text drag into the white boxes. However, onDrop is not firing, and as a result the text is not being dropped into the box.

HTML Boxes:

```
        <div
          id="itemSpot1"
          className="target"
          onDrop={(event) => handleDrop(event)}
          onDragOver={(event) => handleDragOver(event)}
        ></div>
       
        <div
          id="div1"
          className="target"
          data-name="down"
          onDragOver={(event) => handleDragOver(event)}
          onDragLeave={(event) => handleDragLeave(event)}
        ></div>

        <div
          id="item1"
          className="element"
          draggable="true"
          onDragStart={(event) => handleDragStart(event)}
        >
          Item 1
        </div>
```

onDrop functions:

```
  let offset = [0, 0];

  const handleDrop = (event) => {
    drop(event);
    console.log("drop");
  };

  function drop(ev) {
    console.log("In the function");
    //item name being dropped
    ev.preventDefault();
    const data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("dragID"); // transfers image
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)); // changes the child event

    var direction = ev.target.getAttribute("data-name"); //gets direction from html
    if (direction === "left") {
      
      // Takes the item Name and sends the name to another div tag at the bottom of the screen
      let text = document.getElementById(data).textContent;
      document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = text;
      let divpos = ev.target.id;
      let pos = divpos.substring(3);
      // console.log(pos);
      document.getElementById("tempPos").innerHTML = pos;
    } else if (direction === "right") {
      let text = document.getElementById(data).textContent;
      document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = text;
      let divpos = ev.target.id;
      let pos = divpos.substring(3);
      // console.log(pos);
      document.getElementById("tempPos").innerHTML = pos;
    } else if (direction === "down") {
      let text = document.getElementById(data).textContent;
      document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = text;
      let divpos = ev.target.id;
      let pos = divpos.substring(3);
      document.getElementById("tempPos").innerHTML = pos;
      // console.log(pos);
    } 

  }

  function checkChildren() {
    const collection = document.getElementsByClassName("target");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(collection, (element) => {
      if (element.children.length === 0) {
        element.style.backgroundImage = "";
        element.style.border = "1px solid black";
        console.log("check");
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-resonance-qu1qoj?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't attach the `handleDrop()` function to the target div's. You only attached the `handleDrop()` function to the divs that already have the draggable item in it. So your target div's currently look like this:

```
<div
  id="div1"
  className="target"
  data-name="down"
  onDragOver={(event) => handleDragOver(event)}
  onDragLeave={(event) => handleDragLeave(event)}
></div>
```

and they should have the handleDrop function attached like so:

```
<div
  id="div1"
  className="target"
  data-name="down"
  onDrop={(event) => handleDrop(event)}
  onDragOver={(event) => handleDragOver(event)}
  onDragLeave={(event) => handleDragLeave(event)}
></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that!